# How can I make all the mesh peaks at same height?

Tags: mesh, vertices, transforms, normal-map, bump

I have a relief mesh but I can't figure out how to make the same peak height across the full length of the curve. I tried to align the peaks with scale but the result was not good.[image: The contour of the peaks is like the red wave, I want to make them like the green line]

Comment: How are you generating the mesh?

Comment: Displacement modifier